# How to return an array when calling a solidity function?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-invocation, react

Yo I'm pretty new to coding so bear with me. I'm using ReactJS with web3 to call functions from a smart contract but the function I'm trying to call returns an array and I can't figure out how to return the array using web3.

When I try to call the function it just returns:

```
Object { 0: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 1: [], tokens: [] }
```

```
const ownedTokens = () => {
  blockchain.smartContract.methods
    .ownedTokens()
    .call().then((tokens) => {
      console.log(tokens)
    });
};
```

This is the solidity function I'm trying to call

```
function ownedTokens() public view returns(address, uint256[] memory tokens){
  return(msg.sender, addressesVault[msg.sender].ownedTokens);
}
```

and the struct it's taking from

```
struct addresses{
        uint256[] ownedTokens;
    }

    mapping(address => addresses) addressesVault;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because `msg.sender` is set to `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` when you use the `call` method. So you should set `from` value when calling the `call` method to set `msg.sender` like this:

```
    const ownedTokens = () => {
  blockchain.smartContract.methods
    .ownedTokens()
    .call({from: '0x1a7d5bF03d2a72494B9487fF0E0B9491c13965B4'}, function(error, tokens){
        console.log(tokens); 
   });;
};
```

In place of `0x1a7d5bF03d2a72494B9487fF0E0B9491c13965B4` set the address you want the `msg.sender` to be.

[Ref](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#id26)